# Windows uses DNS server from Wifi NIC rather than cabled NIC, despite cable having lower metric

Tags: windows, networking, dns

At work we have both a guest wifi and wired lan.

When Im plugged in to the lan and have the wifi turned off, I get a local dns server which resolves internal servers correctly.

But if I have my wifi enabled and both cabled and wireless networks are enabled, the dns server from the wifi is being used.

My wired NIC has a lower metric, so Id think the DNS server from that NIC should be chosen, but this seems not to be the case.

How can i tell windows to use our local DNS when connected to the LAN even if wireless connection is enabled and connected to guest network?

This is on windows 7.

thanks in advance

Comment: Just the DNS? Here on both windows system XP and 7 , having an active Wireless (internet) connection overrides the wired and many times faster Lan connection for all the internet access stuff.   I just disable the wireless with devcon. (or the other or both as desired) Mabey what your talking about is the way it all clings in the caches?  Then there are programs that also have thier own ways of doing dns caching too. Do you have specific programs that are important to the question?

Comment: To clarify, is this your situation: Machine gets DNS servers by DHCP on two connections (possibly at different times). Both connections are operational, and you want to control which connection's DNS server settings are used. (Also, is this Windows 7?)

Comment: Yes, this is on Windows 7 (updated question). Both DNS servers are given by DHCP, both connections are operational. I could turn off Wifi and be happy, but Im not happy when I have to do work the computer could do for me ;-)
I want it to use the DNS server of the NIC that has lowest metric, i suppose.

Comment: Oh, and ive tried clearing the dns cache, both OS and software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the order in the advanced network settings, as seen in screenshot

[image: Windows advanced network settings]

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar [topic](https://superuser.com/questions/43387/when-concurrently-connected-to-wired-and-wireless-ensure-windows-7-uses-wired-co) on this subject. Key bit of info is the last post basically saying all the obvious things don't work and suggesting a Microsoft workaround.